# Internship and college credit

Tags: hiring-process, internship, compensation

I was offered an internship with a decent compensation, however, I recently discovered my educational institution also offers an internship 'course' for credit with a internship report at the end. I was reading that perhaps since the company will see that I am getting credit for this internship they will rescind my compensation.

Is this a likely scenario or am I just overthinking this, receiving credit and compensation is the best of both worlds.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Acedemics not navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you are over thinking this and going towards a worst case scenario that is not likely.  It is, however, good to verify.

I went to a university that not only offered, but required internship credits for their engineering degrees, and the work was always compensated.  Companies that advertised through the university knew the deal and were prepared for it.  For a company, working with a university to get interns means you usually get a really good sense of what the interns can do, and you get input into helping the educational program so that each year the interns actually get better.  In return the college expects the company to do some paperwork and provide feedback to the university in a particular format that can be used by both the school and the student for self-improvement.

If you are working with a company that you connected to through your school, it doesn't hurt to verify - call your recruitment contact and make sure that they are aware you want to do the internship for a college credit.

If you are working with a place that you found *without* working with your school, and you want credit for it in the university, you may need to be prepared to do some administrative work.

- Talk to your school and find out what the process is for you to get credit.  Make sure you know what the employer has to do.
- Schedule a talk with the employer so you can discuss the needs for the credit program.  Have the paperwork they need to do ready and figure out with them who can do the paperwork.  Do this before you show up on site that first day and make sure you have names and dates planned with them, so that everything happens on time.
- Manage the dates.  Make sure the employer doesn't forget and verify with the school that the papers are complete.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact the university/college to see what their policy is. They might limit credit to only unpaid internships. They might require information from the employer in addition to your report, therefor both sides could realize that there is pay or credit involved.

The recent court decisions in the US have limited the number of unpaid internships unless they can show that the person gets a benefit worth more than the company gets in free labor. Of course budget cuts and the poor economy have reduced the number of paid internships.

Some companies give you a choice for credit or for pay. They have a different number of slots available in each program. They may also have different numbers of hours available for each program. For credit interns can work as many hours as they need to meet their university requirements. Paid interns can work until the money runs out.

Also keep in mind that you probably will end up paying tuition for those credits. You will have to considered that into your equation if you need to decide if you want to go with paid: but no credit; or unpaid but for credit.